# How to remove numbering of theorems etc. on LyX

Tags: numbering, lyx, theorems

Is there a way to put a command in my LyX document preamble to inhibit numeration of theorems, propositions, and definitions in the whole document?

Comment: I never make theorems or the like, but I see that there is a module called "Theorems (unnumbered)". Could it work to replace whatever theorem module you have used with that?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a numbered Theorems module loaded, just
choose `Theorem*`, `Proposition*`, 
or `Definition*` from the drop-down menu at the top left.

I have the Italian version:

[image]

If you don't have a numbered Theorems module loaded, go to 
`Document -> Settings -> Modules`, choose `Theorems (Unnumbered)` 
and click `Add`.

[image]

Then, from the drop-down menu at the top left, you can choose `Theorem` (or `Theorem*`), 
`Proposition` (or `Proposition*`), 
or `Definition` (or `Definition*`).

Comment: @ZakariaeBenSlimane You're welcome! Please consider accepting my answer, see this link if you don't know how to do it: [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852).